# Можно ли наследоваться от std::vector<T>::iterator? C++

Tags: c++, vector, итераторы

Нужно получить класс, который будет итератором для моего контейнера и он лишь немного отличается по функционалу от `std::vector<T>::iterator`, хочу унаследоваться от векторного итератора и переопределить в нем несколько операторов. Вопрос вот в чем: наследуются ли операторы? В итераторе для вектора все операторы объявлены не виртуальными. Если просто перекрыть методы базового класса-итератора, то это может привести к проблемам с динамическим связыванием. Я знаю, что не наследуются операторы присваивания, но что насчет операторов сравнения, разыменовывания и так далее?

Comment: А что конкретно ваш итератор делает?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat если вкратце, то итерируется по двум векторам. Но это не важно. Если я хочу переопределить работу какого-либо оператора в итераторе для вектора, то мне придется писать свой итератор и свой контейнер с нуля? Нет вариантов с наследованием? Ведь простым перекрытием мы проложим себе путь к ошибкам с кастованием

Comment: Я бы написал свой итератор, не так уж это и долго. Но проблем с наследованием быть не должно, вряд ли кто-то догадается кастовать итератор в родителя...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну при передаче в std фунцию вызываться будет вариант родителя, например

Comment: В смысле в функции самого вектора? Угу. Поэтому и стал бы свой писать.

Comment: Итератор вектора и array-я, в отличии от итераторов других контейнеров, не обязаны быть классом. (Может быть голым указателем.) Поэтому, унаследоваться от него может оказаться невозможно, по крайней мере в некоторых реализациях stl.

Comment: @Chorkov интересно, а где можно прочитать про эти случаи? В документации у вектора в качестве типа `iterator` действительно нет конкретного класса. Лишь заметки, что этот тип удовлетворяет `RandomAccessIterator` условиям